# Utilize on.("submit") With HTML Form Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, onsubmit

Could anyone give me a clue as to why this would not work.

I have a form:

```
<form id="add">
    .
    .
    .
    <button id="button1" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And want to make inputs within the form readonly on submit (I know there is better ways to accomplish this but I am looking at this specific situation).

Why would this jquery not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#add").on("submit", "input", function(event) {
        console.log("hello");
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).prop("readonly", true);
    });

});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're passing `input` as the second argument of `on` so essentially listening for a `submit` event on `#add input`. There's no `submit` event on inputs. Remove that second argument and you'll be fine.

Comment: `#add input` => Doing this will **not** submit the form then.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. `$('#add').on('submit', 'input', ...)` is the same as doing `$('#add input').on('submit', ...)`, (expect the first one would take into account inputs added to the DOM later on but that's not the point here), which is why it didn't work.

Comment: Its actually not the same apparently you are `event binding` the submit on an input which is a part of the form. Thats means your `eventDelegation` is on the inputs which are in the form - so doing this way will always refresh the page and will not submit the form nor set the prop to readonly. In a nutshell it will not do anything. You can try the example.

Comment: I know that. I was just explaining what the OP did and why it didn't work. How many times do I need to repeat it?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually not adding a `readonly` attribute on your `inputs` on submit event but `$(this)` actually refers to the whole HTML `form` - which you can not apply readonly attribute to.

**Why your example does not work:** You are event binding the form submit on an input which is a part of the form. That means your `eventDelegation` is on the `inputs` which are in the form and the `submit` handler is a button `type="submit"`- so doing this way will always refresh the page and will **not** submit the form **nor** set the prop to `readonly`. In a nutshell it will not do anything at all because the `eventDelegation` is incorrect.

To enable all the inputs `readyOnly` on form submit you can use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method `jQuery` and looks for all `:input` including any `textarea` if you have one as well.

```
$(this).find(':input').prop("readonly", true); //prop all readonly
```

Also, you do **not** need to add `input` in your submit event function as well.

**Working Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).find(':input').prop("readonly", true); //prop all readonly
    console.log("form submitted - all inputs are readonly now");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form id="add">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Some value" />
  <br>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Some other value" />
  <br>
  <textarea class="form-control">I am a textarea</textarea>
  <br>
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="button1" type="submit">Click me to submit</button>
</form>
```